# Error Using Grails error.gsp and GrailsWrappedRuntimeException

Tags: grails

After taking an exception and turning it into a GrailsWrappedRuntimeException the renderException tag throws an error.

**Controller Code:**

```
def onError(Exception e) {
        def ge = new GrailsWrappedRuntimeException( servletContext, e )
        assert ge instanceof GrailsWrappedRuntimeException
        render(view: "/error", model: [ exception: ge ])
    }
```

**error.gsp**

```
<g:renderException exception="${exception}" />
```

**Exception:**

```
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib.prettyPrintStatus() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:renderException>: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib.prettyPrintStatus() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
```

Comment: Doing `assert ge instanceof GrailsWrappedRuntimeException` immediately after `def ge = new GrailsWrappedRuntimeException( servletContext, e )` makes no sense.  There is no way `ge` could ever be anything other than a `GrailsWrappedRuntimeException`.

Comment: Agreed. It was a sanity check on my part since I was getting an error further down the road

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the attribute name "exception" is special to the Grails error handling mechanism.   Looks to me like that attribute name is being overridden by the grails default error handling mechanism somehow.  If I change the name to something else like "foo_exception" in the controller and the error.gsp  then the page displays the exception passed to onError correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I have to create a tabLib with the next script, in grails 2.5.0, for send reports to mail, and show error.gsp

```
import grails.util.Environment
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.Encoder
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.ExceptionUtils
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

class SendMailErrorTagLib extends RenderTagLib{
    def mailService

    def reporteDeError = {Map attrs, body ->
        //verify if an exception
        if (!(attrs?.exception instanceof Throwable)) {
            return
        }
        Throwable exception = (Throwable)attrs.exception
        Encoder htmlEncoder = codecLookup.lookupEncoder('HTML')

        //type and cause of the exception
        int statusCode = request.getAttribute('javax.servlet.error.status_code') as int
        def root = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(exception)

        //I build html report for the mail body
        String bodyHtml=
                """
                <h1>
                    Error ${prettyPrintStatus(statusCode)}
                </h1>
                <dl class="error-details">
                    <dt>
                        URI
                    </dt>
                <dd>
                    ${htmlEncoder.encode(WebUtils.getForwardURI(request) ?:
                    request.getAttribute('javax.servlet.error.request_uri'))}
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    Class
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    ${root?.getClass()?.name ?: exception.getClass().name}
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    Message
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    ${htmlEncoder.encode(exception.message)}
                </dd>"""

        if (root != null && root != exception && root.message != exception.message) {
            bodyHtml=bodyHtml+
                "<dt>" +
                    "Caused by" +
                "</dt>" +
                "<dd>" +
                    "${htmlEncoder.encode(root.message)}" +
                "</dd>"
        }
        bodyHtml=bodyHtml+
                "</dl>"

        bodyHtml=bodyHtml+errorsViewStackTracePrinter.prettyPrintCodeSnippet(exception)

        def trace = errorsViewStackTracePrinter.prettyPrint(exception.cause ?: exception)
        if (StringUtils.hasText(trace.trim())) {
            bodyHtml=bodyHtml+
                "<h2>" +
                    "Trace" +
                "</h2>"
            bodyHtml=bodyHtml+
                '<pre class="stack">'
            bodyHtml=bodyHtml+htmlEncoder.encode(trace)
            bodyHtml=bodyHtml+
                '</pre>'
        }
        //configure and send email in test or prod enviroment....
        mailService.sendMail {
            to "samuel@tequilasoft.mx" //madlogproduccion@tequilasoft.com
            from "noreply.asistenteacademico@gmail.com"
            subject "Reporte de errores en Asistente Academico, ambiente: $Environment.current"
            html bodyHtml
        }
    }
}
```

And use this new tagLib "g:renderException" obviously, and my file error.gsp change like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <g:if env="development">
                Grails Runtime Exception
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                Error
            </g:else>
        </title>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:if env="development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'errors.css')}" type="text/css">
        </g:if>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:if env="development">
            <g:renderException exception="${exception}" />
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
            <ul class="errors">
                <li>
                    An error has occurred
                </li>
            </ul>
        </g:else>
    </body>
</html>
```